# Managing selenium grids/nodes

Tags: selenium-grid

Currently we are running the selenium grid on a Windows 7 vm and we have about 10 other win 7 vms for the nodes. We periodically run into some problems where the node stops working and just needs to be restarted. We also would like a periodic restart. I am curious how others are managing/ monitoring the nodes to see when something fails. Not sure if there is a way to monitor with something like Nagios?

I thought for restarting that I could try to build the node jar as a reservice and just have a schedule to reboot it once a month. Thoughts? Do I need to elaborate some more? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try selenium-grid-extras. Its been open sourced by groupon, I believe. From their git hub page:

This project is designed to help you manage your Selenium Grid installation by giving you control over the Grid Hub machine and Grid Node machine. This is very useful in cases when Internet Explorer Driver crashes, and you need to kill the iedriver.exe so that next test can start and not fail.

Link to the page - https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras